# Processing output highmap by displacement mapping on surface of a sphere

Tags: processing

Processing output highmap by displacement mapping on surface of a sphere, like drawing hills on a shpere surface.

```
import peasy.*;
PShape ico1;

int level = 6; 
float hgt=0;

String[] imgname={"0.jpg","1.jpg","2.jpg"};
PImage[] images = new PImage[imgname.length];
int textImg=0;
float pz;
PVector rotation = new PVector(); 
PVector velocity = new PVector(); 
float rotationSpeed = 0.02; 

PShader texs;
void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000, P3D); 

  for(int i = 0; i<imgname.length;i++)images[i] = loadImage(imgname[i]);
  images[0].loadPixels();

  ico1 = createIcosahedron(level,textImg); //see example of processing for code of class Icosahedron,but init() and create() in a method createIcosahedron(level,textImg) and return the class Icosahedron.
  noLoop();
  for (int i = 0 ; i<ico1.getVertexCount(); i+=1){
      PVector vtemp=ico1.getVertex(i);
      pz=brightness(images[0].get((int)(ico1.getTextureU(i)),(int)(ico1.getTextureV(i))))*16;
      vtemp=vtemp.set(vtemp.x,vtemp.y,pz);
      ico1.setVertex(i,vtemp);
  }
  loop();

}

void draw() {
  background(240);
  translate(width/2, height/2); 
  scale(250); 
  //pointLight(255, 255, 255, 2*(mouseX-width/2), 2*(mouseY-height/2), 500);
  shader(texs);
   ambientLight(100, 102, 126);

  shape(ico1); 


}

  }
}
```

The above missing some unrelated codes, the above show no output when run. please help show the error.
Please see example of processing for code of class Icosahedron,but init() and create() in a method createIcosahedron(level,textImg) and return the class Icosahedron. You can search google for "processing Icosahedron" for codes, but really does not matter.

Comment: Sorry, the UV is added to the processing example of Icosahedron by ico1.getTextureU(int index) and ico1.getTextureV(int index)

Comment: I am afraid that Highmaps doesn't offer any possibility to draw a custom sphere surface. What Highmaps offers you can easily find here: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo and here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to modify the 3D geometry of the subdivided icosahedron based on a heightmap texture, a bit like **Processing > Examples > Demos > Graphics > Mesh Tweening**:

[image: mesh tweening processing sample flat plane with a grayscale texture]

[image: mesh tweening processing sample distorted plane with a mountains/valleys based on grayscale values]

Bare in mind you are doing this on surface that is not a flat plane, so offsetting z might not get you the effect you're after since that z would change depending on which side of the icosahedron you are.

this part:

```
PVector vtemp=ico1.getVertex(i);
      pz=brightness(images[0].get((int)(ico1.getTextureU(i)),(int)(ico1.getTextureV(i))))*16;
      vtemp=vtemp.set(vtemp.x,vtemp.y,pz);
      ico1.setVertex(i,vtemp);
```

would need to change.

You would need to compute the normal(perpendicular) at that vertex position: this will tell you in which direction to go taking into account the angle on the icosahedron surface.

Scaling (multiplying) this vector by an elevation value (the uv mapped brightness value) would offset that whole normal in the same direction but either more outward or inward in relation to the icosahedron.

Simply add the vertex position to the scaled vertex normal to translate it to the right position. Something like:

```
PVector vtemp = ico1.getVertex(i);
float elevation = brightness(images[0].get((int)(ico1.getTextureU(i)),(int)(ico1.getTextureV(i))))*16 

PVector vNormal = getVertexNormal(vtemp);

PVector elevatedVertex = PVector.add(vtemp, PVector.mult(vNormal,elevation));

ico1.setVertex(i,elevatedVertex);
```

Where `getVertexNormal()` would calculate or retrieve a pre-calculated vertex normal for that vertex. There are multiple resources out there, here's one on [Computer Graphics StackExchange](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/programmatically-generating-vertex-normals)

Here's a visual explanation using Blender:
[image: Blender subdivided Icosahedron mesh selected vertex normal translation]

I recommend checking out the [HE_Mesh Processing library](https://github.com/wblut/HE_Mesh) (which you can install easily via Contribution Manager) as it would provide a wealth of 3D geometry tools.

Additionally, if you could also look into displacement mapping and/or [normal mapping](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/)